# Improved indices trick

Tags: c++, c++11

We all know about the [indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks%3aindices), right? Here's (hopefully) an improved version...

```
template <::std::size_t...> struct indices { };

namespace detail
{

template<class A, class B> struct catenate_indices;

template <::std::size_t ...Is, ::std::size_t ...Js>
struct catenate_indices<indices<Is...>, indices<Js...> >
{
  using indices_type = indices<Is..., Js...>;
};

template <::std::size_t, ::std::size_t, typename = void> struct expand_indices;

template <::std::size_t A, ::std::size_t B>
struct expand_indices<A, B, typename ::std::enable_if<A == B>::type>
{
  using indices_type = indices<A>;
};

template <::std::size_t A, ::std::size_t B>
struct expand_indices<A, B, typename ::std::enable_if<A != B>::type>
{
  static_assert(A < B, "A > B");
  using indices_type = typename catenate_indices<
    typename expand_indices<A, (A + B) / 2>::indices_type,
    typename expand_indices<(A + B) / 2 + 1, B>::indices_type
  >::indices_type;
};

}

template <::std::size_t A>
struct make_indices : detail::expand_indices<0, A>::indices_type
{
};

template <::std::size_t A, ::std::size_t B>
struct make_indices_range : detail::expand_indices<A, B>::indices_type
{
};
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "utility.hpp"

template <::std::size_t ...Is>
void show_indices(indices<Is...>)
{
  [](...){}((((::std::cout << Is << ::std::endl), 0))...);
}

int main()
{
  show_indices(make_indices_range<3, 9>());

  return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get rid of the `<type_traits>` header by replacing your `std::enable_if` by a `bool` template specialization:

```
template <::std::size_t, ::std::size_t, bool>
struct expand_indices_impl;

template <::std::size_t A, ::std::size_t B>
struct expand_indices:
    expand_indices_impl<A, B, A==B>
{};

template <::std::size_t A, ::std::size_t B>
struct expand_indices_impl<A, B, true>
{
    using indices_type = indices<A>;
};

template <::std::size_t A, ::std::size_t B>
struct expand_indices_impl<A, B, false>
{
    static_assert(A < B, "A > B");
    using indices_type = typename catenate_indices<
        typename expand_indices<A, (A + B) / 2>::indices_type,
        typename expand_indices<(A + B) / 2 + 1, B>::indices_type
    >::indices_type;
};
```

---

Moreover, in C++ (and many other programming languages, see Python `range` for example), ranges tend to have the end-exclusive form `[begin, end)`; therefore, `make_indices_range<3, 9>` should contain the indices from 3 to 8, and not from 3 to 9. It is easy to alter the behaviour:

```
template <::std::size_t A>
struct make_indices:
    detail::expand_indices<0, A-1>::indices_type
{};

template <::std::size_t A, ::std::size_t B>
struct make_indices_range:
    detail::expand_indices<A, B-1>::indices_type
{};
```

As proposed in the comments, `make_indices_range` also needs to provide an empty range when `A == B`:

```
template <::std::size_t A>
struct make_indices_range<A, A>:
    indices<>
{};
```

Comment: You did not provide for the special case of `make_indices_range<A, A>` in which case you need to inherit from `indices<>`.

Comment: @user1095108 Well, that's actually a good idea :)